# How to address SHIM_NOVERSION_FOUND error message

Tags: .net, c++-cli, .net-4.5

I am updating a C++/CLI mixed mode executable from VS 2010 to VS 2012.  We're targeting .NET 4.5, and the VS2012 toolset.

It's building and running perfectly in Debug builds, but the Release builds immediately exit with "This application could not be started." and a link which goes to a [Microsoft Support page](http://support.microsoft.com/kb/2715633?version=%28null%29&processName=evs_mvs.exe&platform=0009&osver=6&isServer=0) suggesting that the problem is `SHIM_NOVERSION_FOUND`.

The page in question states "You can't fix the configuration problem yourself. Contact the app vendor to resolve the issue."  As the app vendor in question, I'm having difficulty discovering any information on how to approach correcting this application.

Where does the application go to discover the proper .NET version in a C++ project, and how do you go about adding the proper information to the .vcxproj or Solution files in order to get it to build properly?

Comment: Do release builds exit with that error, even on the machine that built the application?

Comment: @DavidYaw Yes.  I'm trying to fix the build system to migrate, and get this immediately on startup (even running from within Visual Studio).

Comment: @CurtNichols I can do this, and it changes the behavior, but is not the "solution".  First, for some reason, debug builds do not require this (and shouldn't, from my understanding).  When doing this, release builds no longer show the error, but instead immediately exit (prior to even hitting the first line of code if I step into the program).  It seems like msbuild isn't performing some required step on release builds, but I can't figure out why, and the vcxproj files are huge...

Answer (score 3):

I ran into a similar issue, and I had to do two things: use a config file, and install Framework 4.0 on the target machine. @CurtNichols pointed in that direction, but here's the link that eventually pulled it all together: [How to: Configure an Application to Support .NET Framework 4 or 4.5](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/jj152935.aspx).

Here's the app.config that I ended up with:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8" ?>
<configuration>
  <startup>
    <supportedRuntime version="v4.0"/>
  </startup>
</configuration>
```

Actually, it took quite a few steps to get from point A to point B, so here is "the rest of the story":

- I started out getting a "failed to initialize properly" error, which I had corrected on my XP-loaded Virtual PC by installing Framework 4.0 on it.
- So I tried installing Framework 4.5 on the target machine (a Windows 7 box)
- Now I was getting the `SHIM_NOVERSION_FOUND` error.
- I tried installing Framework 4.0, but of course that was redundant because 4.5 upgrades 4.0.
- I tried installing Framework 3.5, but the installer initialized and then did nothing. Oops, I didn't know that 3.5 is included in Windows 7.
- So I uninstalled Framework 4.5. Not surprisingly, I went back to "failed to initialize properly".
- Another Stack Overflow post (which I can't find now, sorry) suggested checking in Windows Features, to be sure "Microsoft Framework 3.5.1" was fully enabled. On the target machine, the "Windows Communication Foundation" sub-options were unchecked. So I checked them... and got the same result.
- I installed Framework 4.0 (which I could do now, because I uninstalled 4.5). Just to be sure, I rebooted. Still got something like "unable to find a version of the runtime".
- Now, I finally gave up and added the app.config settings referenced in the MSDN entry. But first, I tried it like this, which was supposed to say that I would be fine with 3.5 or 4.0:

  ```
  <supportedRuntime version="v2.0.50727"/> 
  <supportedRuntime version="v4.0"/>
  ```
- That was a mistake... probably because I originally compiled in a 4.0 environment. I got an error like "has stopped working".
- So I got rid of the 3.5 specification (aka 2.0.5xxx because Microsoft), and it works as though that's what I was supposed to have done in the first place. (Which it probably was.)

Hope the details of the process help someone!

Answer (score 0):

Here's what worked for me:

Project Properties > Build > Platform target: Any CPU